# Dynamic menu versus hard-coded

Tags: jquery-mobile, cordova

I'm working on building a mobile application for a client using jQuery Mobile. The question I have is fairly basic and non-technical:

The application can have three different types of users, all with a different menu layout. Some users will have access to some parts of the system that other users will not.

My question is- should I hardcode the menu system in the index.html file or should I dynamically create it when they log in? I'm assuming that there would be a slight performance gain by hardcoding the menu and then just choosing which #page to display as opposed to requiring an ajax call...but keeping the menu builder on the server side processing keeps us more agile if need to change the menu after deployment.

Deep apologies if this has already been asked. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Build your pages dynamically. On jQuery mobile, a lot of stuff will be repeated and if you want to respect the [DRY principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself) and want to create easily maintainable code, do it dynamically.

Also, by doing this on a mobile application you will reduce the loading times : instead of loading 3 pages you'll only load one, wich can be crucial in mobile developpement.

Comment: So the load time gained by only loading one #page is better than the extra network usage needed to fetch the JSON from the server? That is what I am currently doing, but just wanted to clarify that what I'm thinking is correct.

Comment: Well that would require some more research but IMHO yes. Especially if your pages contain much images and ressources.

Answer (score 1):

Hard coding is bad if it can be done dynamically do it because it saves over head and produces nicer code that is easier maintainable.

If you want to change the menu in the future you can just edit the source of information instead of going through all your code having tons of messy if and else statements saying if this person is logged in don't show this option but show this one etc.